# C# .NET 3.5: Memory Pool, know when object is released?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection, .net-3.5

I'm in a situation where I'm having to create thousands of objects at once, and the cost of instantiating the objects and garbage collecting them is impacting the performance of the application, and the impact of the garbage collector running hurts the performance more since this is on older hardware, so I'm mostly trying to prevent the creation of garbage. I believe a memory pool would solve my issue but I'm not sure how the memory pool would know when a resource in the pool was freed up for re-use. The tricky part is that receiver of objects from the pool end up passing that object around throughout the program and it would be very difficult to know when it could be manually freed up. I'd like it to be like a `WeakReference`, where I could know when nobody was using it anymore. But my understanding is that if I use a `WeakReference` in the memory pool then it would eventually get garbage collected from the pool itself and I need these objects to remain pretty much forever so they'll continue to get recycled. Sometimes the program can go for awhile without needing the objects so I imagine the garbage collector would collect them before the next time when they were needed and that would then trigger another performance hit as another thousand of these objects were made.

Is there a way I can make sure these objects are never collected, but know when there are no references to them aside from the memory pool itself? Do I need to implement reference counting for these objects somehow?

I've been googling for a couple of hours now and have seen no implementation of a Memory Pool that doesn't require the user to let the memory pool know when they're done with it. I find it hard to believe there is no way to do this in C#.

Comment: In regards specifically to the question `is there a way to know when there are no references aside  from the memory pool itself?` There are countless questions that ask this already: See this search for example: https://www.google.ca/search?q=get%20all%20active%20object%20references%20C%23&rct=j Its impossible to give suggestions because i don't know the inner workings of your program, but i'd suggest trying to tackle this a different/better way. There is almost always a better way and IMO trying to create, track references to, and re-used 1000's of objects isn't very good.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, which is why I asked in the first place. I need to use these objects, and thousands of queries are being made that return those objects. Having to create 1000s of new ones is inefficient. I'm not sure what the alternative would be.

Comment: Are you very sure this is a performance issue?  Because most of the proposed 'solutions' here sound a lot worse. Try to make those objects as short-lived as possible and analyze carefully.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: there are two performance issues. Having to make 1000 queries is one of them, I'm trying to optimize that separately. However, creating almost any garbage is bad for performance for this application, as we're running on older mobile devices and a lot of other things are happening in the app. I need to avoid garbage while doing this stuff.

Comment: You should add the tags for the mobile (embedded?) platform, makes a lot of difference.

Comment: I added a tag for iOS, but really iOS is not the problem, it's that 3+ year old iOS devices are just slow.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can make sure these objects are never collected, but know when there are no references to them aside from the memory pool itself?

Usually an object pool only holds references to available objects (you can check [`ObjectPool` implementation in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a4e375b95953e471660e9686a46893c97db70b0e/src/Compilers/Core/SharedCollections/ObjectPool%601.cs)). With that in mind, you can use the finalizer to resurrect the object and return it to the pool when it is unreachable.

However, I don't think it will improve performance. The whole pool will very soon reach generation 2, so the unreachable objects will need a full garbage collection to be returned to the pool. Depending on the memory usage pattern in your program, it might not happen very often. You can `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` of course, but it will also hurt performance. You can try it out and check if it helps.

Another problem is the design - your objects are coupled to the pool.

I'd rather try to return the objects to the pool explicitly. Remember that not all objects have to be returned. If there are no more available objects, the pool can create new ones. The ones that were not returned will just be garbage collected. Check if there are some code paths where you are sure the objects are not needed anymore. If you can't find any, try to refactor your code.

Comment: Garbage collection is one of main issues, I need to avoid creating garbage. A memory pool is supposed to allow you to recycle objects to prevent the creation of garbage. It just doesn't seem like C# has the language tools to allow me to reference count things given out by the pool so that I can know when they're no longer in use outside the pool. If I have to wait for the finalizer then it's already too late and the GC will be coming for that object soon, right?

Comment: There is no reference counting in C#. The finalizer runs after the garbage collector determines that the object is unreachable. So if the real performance issue is the garbage collection, not object instantiation then an object pool based on GC will not help at all. If the instantiation causes performance issues, you could even try to make an object pool without returning any objects to it. Create a low-priority background thread that will refill the pool. The objects obtained from the pool will be GCed, but new ones will be created while the application is mostly idle.

Comment: Creating new ones is less of a problem then the GC running to get the old ones. On older mobile devices when GC runs it hits the framerate pretty hard. I'm mostly looking to avoid GC. C++ doesn't have reference counting either, but the language itself allows someone to write an automatic reference counting system, like Boost did with smart pointers. I was hoping there was a way to accomplish this with C# as well.

Comment: @NicFoster I don't know of any way to do it in C#. If we're talking about an old mobile device, additional memory used by the object pool might be a problem too. It might actually cause more GC when other parts of the app need to allocate memory.